# create-react-app subfolder projects do not lint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, eslint

Projects bootstrapped with create-react-app within subfolders do not lint.  However, if I open the project subfolder as root in VSCode (pictured below), or setup a new create-react-app project at root, linting works fine.

[image]

This occurs with both standard and ejected create-react-app projects.

Ideally without ejecting, how can I make create-react-app's linting work with subfolder projects?

I'm using create-react-app v3.1.1, VSCode August 2019 and Windows 10.

Comment: eslint plugin 2.0.0+ can support things like `{"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "pattern": "./*" }]}` and `{"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]}`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The **[VSCode ESLint Extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint)** includes settings for specifying working directories:

> an array for working directories to be used. ESLint resolves
>   configuration files (e.g. eslintrc) relative to a working directory.
>   This new settings allows users to control which working directory is
>   used for which files.

Therefore, in this case, adding the following to the Workspace `settings.json` file solves the issue:

```
{
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        "./client"
    ]
}
```