# VSCode failed to load plugin cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, eslintrc

I'm installing `eslint` and `Prettier` in my project and trying to get automatic code formatting to work through VSCode. When I go to a React file, I see that ESLint is in error so I open up the ESLint console where I see:

> Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in 'js/.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'

I believe I have all the necessary modules installed, here is a piece of my `package.json` file:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "prettier": "1.19.1"
  }
```

The only thing I can think of is that this is being caused by my project directory structure, which is as follows:

```
/
(some Java stuff out here)
js/
  node_modules/
  package.json
  package-lock.json
  .eslintrc.js
  .prettierrc
```

For reference, here is my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
      browser: true,
      node: true
    },
    parserOptions: {
      parser: 'babel-eslint',
      ecmaVersion: 2015,
      sourceType: 'module'
    },
    extends: [
      'prettier',
      'plugin:prettier/recommended'
    ],
    plugins: [
        'react',
        'prettier'
    ],
    rules: {
    }
  }
```

For further reference, here is my `settings.json` in VSCode:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    // turn it off for JS and JSX, we will do this via eslint
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    // tell the ESLint plugin to run on save
    "eslint.validate": [ "vue", "html", "javascript", "javascriptreact"],
    "prettier.disableLanguages": [
        "javascript", "javascriptreact"
    ],
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        { "mode": "auto" }
    ],
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
}
```

**Update:** It seems like this is an issue with VSCode doing autoformatting on subdirectories. Once I opened just the subdirectory as the "project root" in VSCode then it started doing all the formatting for me on save. I'm still curious if I can get this working without this workaround.

Comment: Same observation for me

Answer (score 34, accepted):

i had the same issue.

In your root workspace you have a `.vscode` folder with a `settings.json`.

Add the following:

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "./{PATH_TO_CLIENT}" // replace {PATH_TO_CLIENT} with you own path
  ]
}
```

related issue: [create-react-app subfolder projects do not lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879267/create-react-app-subfolder-projects-do-not-lint)

Comment: Brilliant. The project I had was in a subfolder, and that fixed it.

Comment: @Julez is `{PATH_TO_CLIENT}` something we need to replace, or is it a special variable we can use as is? I have a bunch of packages in my monorepo under `package/**` can I use a glob?

Comment: @mesqueeb Its something you need to change relative to your project. i was just showing it for reference.

Comment: @Julez do I need to keep the {} in there ?

Comment: No, you replace `{PATH_TO_CLIENT}` with your own path

Comment: In VSCode, you need to `Restart ESLint Server` to see changes take effect

Answer (score 6):

VSCode/eslint will not pick newly installed npm packages in the `node_modules` directory. After running `npm i eslint-plugin-prettier` restart the VSCode workspace. Happens to me consistently, every time I setup a new Javascript/Node/React project and add `eslint` & `prettier`, [using this guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/linting-typescript-using-eslint-and-prettier/) in the order it suggests.

Comment: Restarting vscode fixed it for me too.

Comment: restarting only the eslint service also worked for me instead of the whole VS CODE

Answer (score 1):

try this command will solve your problem: worked for me as well:)
npm i eslint-plugin-prettier@latest -D

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to eslint@7.32.0 fixed the issue for me. Was previously on a ~7.10.0. Be sure to restart VSCode if using it.

```
yarn upgrade eslint
# or
npm update eslint
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution :

Steps :

1. Remove `node_modules` and yarn.lock/npm.lock
2. Reinstall packages with `yarn` or `npm`.
3. Install eslint again with `npm i --save-dev eslint eslint-plugin-jest` or `yarn add --dev eslint eslint-plugin-jest`

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have duplicated copies of eslint in your package i.e. `yarn list eslint` should only return one version. Otherwise de-dedupe by checking the versions in you package.json and ensure that yarn.lock is not interfering.

Answer (score 0):

The ESLint output within vscode hinted at packages installed globally. This was my issue.

If you don't need these packages globally (you usually don't), running:

```
npm uninstall -g eslint
npm uninstall -g eslint-plugin-prettier
```

could fix things

I also recommend running `>ESLint: Restart ESLint Server` in vscode (cmd+p)